# Differentiation of a complex function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to differentiate the below function.

$ F(X) = \biggl(\frac{\sin X}{X}\biggr)^2 \biggl(\frac{5}{5-jX}\biggr)^3\biggl(e^\frac{j4X-16X^2}{2}\biggr)$

Can someone please help me differentiate the above function?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(z)=\frac{sin z}{z}$ is not defined at $z=0$.  If you define $f(0)=1,$ then you can show that $f’(0)=0$ by the definition of derivative or L’Hospital’s rule. Next you can use product rule for derivatives.